# How to remove Edge Text in image using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to remove the text on the edged in the image
I have used the following code but it does not work it also remove the text in the center

Input:

[image: Input Image]

Output:

[image: Output image]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
def crop_buttom_text(img):
    """ Remove the text from the bottom edge of img """
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)  # No need for blurring
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Create rectangular structuring element and dilate
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (30, 1))  # Use horizontal line as kernel - dilate horizontally.
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
    #kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,10))
    #dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)    # No need for opening

    # Find contours and draw rectangle
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).
    #cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1] # [-2] is shorter....

    res_img = img.copy()  # Copy img to res_img - in case there is no edges text.

    for c in cnts:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        y2 = y + h  # Bottom y coordinate of the bounding rectangle

        if (y2 >= img.shape[0]):
            # If the rectangle touches the bottom of the img
            res_img = res_img[0:y-1, :].copy()  # Crop rows from first row to row y-1

    return res_img
def remove_lines(image_path,outdir):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    img1 = crop_buttom_text(image)
    img2 = crop_buttom_text(np.rot90(img1)) # Rotate by 90 degrees and crop.
    img3 = crop_buttom_text(np.rot90(img2)) # Rotate by 90 degrees and crop.
    img4 = crop_buttom_text(np.rot90(img3)) # Rotate by 90 degrees and crop.

    output_img = np.rot90(img4)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(image_path)), output_img)
    
for jpgfile in glob.glob(r'/content/Dataset/*'):
    print(jpgfile)
    remove_lines(jpgfile,r'/content/output')
```

How can i modify the above code to remove the text around the edge

Comment: Why is a binary image provided in JPEG format?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana don't understand your point?

Comment: JPEG is for photographic images and adds spurious colors to your image. Where does the input image come from? Does it come from other processing or is your task to analyze JPEG images? If it comes from other processing provide the input image as PNG (possibly specifying the flags for binary).

Comment: I agree with Costantino.

Comment: @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay How can i modified the code according to that?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana How to solve it?

Comment: Would something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nufhm.png) work?

Comment: You want to "remove the text around the edge". What is "around"? Provide an image in which you color in red the pixels you want to remove and in green those you want to keep. And please answer my question: where do these image come from? Why are they in JPEG format? Can't you threshold them once and save them in PNG?

Comment: For example [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkiyN.png) is what I did. Is it acceptable?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana The Solution you send  in ''Would something like this work?'' i want that kind of solution but still there is comma above how can i also remove that?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I want to keep green text. the image from a paper, what the effect of saving in PNG format?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana did you share the solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you remove the text which is at the edge? Here is a rough way to attack the problem: remove every connected component which touches the border.

To solve this, you can add a 1 pixel border, extract the connected components and then use the one corresponding to the border as a binary mask.

The mask becomes
[image: mask]
The result is
[image: result]

Notice how a 7 and few commas get removed as well.

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np


# Load original image
img = cv2.imread('kShDc.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# Save original dimensions
h, w = img.shape[:2]
# Ensure only bilevel image with white as foreground
_, bimg = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# Add one pixel border
bimg = cv2.copyMakeBorder(bimg, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, 255)
# Extract connected components (Spaghetti is the fastest algorithm)
nlabels, label_image = cv2.connectedComponentsWithAlgorithm(bimg, 8, cv2.CV_32S, cv2.CCL_SPAGHETTI)
# Make a mask with the edge label (0 is background, 1 is the first encountered label, i.e. the border)
ccedge = np.uint8((label_image != 1)*255)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", ccedge, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_BILEVEL, 1])
# Zero every pixel touching the border
bimg = cv2.bitwise_and(bimg, ccedge)
# Remove border and invert again
bimg = 255 - bimg[1:h+1, 1:w+1]
# Save result
cv2.imwrite("result.png", bimg, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_BILEVEL, 1])
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CCL_SPAGHETTI'

Comment: `CCL_DEFAULT` always works. But I strongly suggest to update your OpenCV version.

Comment: I use this code in google colab but it does not work .give the above error

Comment: Change CCL_SPAGHETTI to CCL_DEFAULT.